# Why is an InstantiationException being thrown when a JUnit test attempts to start Seam?

Tags: jakarta-ee, exception, seam, quartz-scheduler, instantiation

I'm attempting to write an Integration Test for an existing Java EE application, which uses Seam and Hibernate and is deployed to Glassfish.

However the test currently fails to start Seam at the very beginning. This seems to be because it can't instantiate the Quartz Scheduler component - see code below. The exception stack trace is also below.

Any help would be much appreciated...

*These may be unnecessary details but I wrote the test using JUnit (rather than TestNG) as described [here](https://community.jboss.org/thread/189670?start=0&tstart=0). The test extends AbstractSeamTest and has @Test methods that instantiate ComponentTest and override testComponents as described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.1.CR1/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e30387). The application is deployed to an existing local Glassfish instance using Cargo in Maven's pre-integration phase and the test is run using the Failsafe plugin.*

InitialiseQuartz class:

```
@Name("initialiseQuartz")
@Scope(ScopeType.APPLICATION)
@Startup
public class InitialiseQuartz {

    private QuartzTriggerHandle qth;

    @In(create=true) 
    private EmailService emailService;

    @Create
    public void startSchedule() {
        System.out.print("Schedule started");
        qth = emailService.generateDailyEmail("0 0 7 * * ?");
    }

    @Destroy
    public void stopSchedule() {
        try {
            qth.cancel();
        } catch (SchedulerException se) {

        }
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
org.jboss.seam.InstantiationException: Could not instantiate Seam component: initialiseQuartz
    at org.jboss.seam.async.AbstractDispatcher.extractAndValidateParameters(AbstractDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.jboss.seam.async.AbstractDispatcher.createTimerSchedule(AbstractDispatcher.java:113)
    at org.jboss.seam.async.ThreadPoolDispatcher.scheduleInvocation(ThreadPoolDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.async.ThreadPoolDispatcher.scheduleInvocation(ThreadPoolDispatcher.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
    at org.jboss.seam.async.ThreadPoolDispatcher_$$_javassist_seam_3.scheduleInvocation(ThreadPoolDispatcher_$$_javassist_seam_3.java)
    at org.jboss.seam.async.AsynchronousInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
    at uk.police.kent.optica.schedule.EmailService_$$_javassist_seam_2.generateDailyEmail(EmailService_$$_javassist_seam_2.java)
    at uk.police.kent.optica.schedule.InitialiseQuartz.startSchedule(InitialiseQuartz.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
    at uk.police.kent.optica.schedule.InitialiseQuartz_$$_javassist_seam_1.startSchedule(InitialiseQuartz_$$_javassist_seam_1.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invokeAndWrap(Reflections.java:144)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.callComponentMethod(Component.java:2275)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.callCreateMethod(Component.java:2198)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2158)
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts.startup(Contexts.java:304)
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts.startup(Contexts.java:278)
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.ServletLifecycle.endInitialization(ServletLifecycle.java:143)
    at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.init(Initialization.java:744)
    at org.jboss.seam.mock.AbstractSeamTest.startSeam(AbstractSeamTest.java:929)
    at com.ipl.rdhi.acceptance.RdhiAdapterIT.setUpBeforeClass(RdhiAdapterIT.java:118)
```

Answer (score 0):

Witch Seam version are you using?

This error occurs usually when some dependency cant be injected into your component. The bean EmailService starts with success in your testcase?

Comment: Seam version 2.2. I think the problem was caused by it failing to start Seam and looking in various forums there seems to be quite a lot of pain involved in getting Seam to work with embedded JBoss. I notice the Seam 2.3 documentation has since abandoned SeamTest in favour of using Arquillian instead but unfortunately that's not an option for me as it's Glassfish version 2.1 and Arquillian only supports 3.1.